# How to automatically restart MySQL and MongoDB when being unresponsive?

Tags: linux, mysql, monitoring, mongodb

I’m running a simple development server (Ubuntu) on which MySQL and MongoDB sometimes crash. I always restart them with `sudo service mysql restart`.

Although I know I need to investigate why they crash—and I will—I’m currently looking for a way to automatically restart them after they've crashed. I guess I need to have some kind of daemon which pings them and restarts them if they are not responsive anymore, but I'm unsure of how to do this.

I read about tools like [Nagios](https://www.nagios.org), but I guess that’s a bit overkill for my situation.

Does anybody know how I can get started?

Comment: I'm having exactly same issue !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I read about tools like [Nagios](https://www.nagios.org), but I guess that’s a bit overkill for
>   my situation.
>
> Does anybody know how I can get started?

Easy. Look into setting up monitoring configurations with [Monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/). It’s a lightweight and easy to setup system monitoring tool that is very useful to setup in scenarios exactly as you describe; service goes down, restart it and alert me about it.

I’ve mainly use it for Apache web servers, but there are [lots of examples of what can be done for other programs/software](https://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/ConfigurationExamples) such as MySQL and such.

#### Setting up Monit.

The way I set it up is line this. First, install the Monit program itself like this:

```
sudo apt-get install monit
```

Once installed, then edit the config here; I prefer to use `nano` but feel free to use whatever text editor you prefer:

```
sudo nano /etc/monit/monitrc
```

Adjust the default daemon values to check services every 60 seconds with a start delay of 120:

```
set daemon 60
with start delay 60
```

Then find the `mailserver` area of `monitrc` and add the following line. Postfix or an SMTP needs to be active for this to work. I typically have Postfix installed on my servers so I use the following setup:

```
set mailserver localhost
```

Then I make sure a Monit config directory is setup like this:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/monit/conf.d
```

#### Setting up a Monit Apache2 monitoring ruleset.

Now—like I said—I mainly use Monit for Apache monitoring so this is a simple config I like to use but the basic concept is similar for MySQL, MongoDB or other things. I would save it in this file:

```
sudo nano /etc/monit/conf.d/apache2.conf
```

And this would be the contents of that file:

```
check process apache with pidfile /var/run/apache2.pid
  start "/usr/sbin/service apache2 start"
  stop  "/usr/sbin/service apache2 stop"
  if failed host 127.0.0.1 port 80
    with timeout 15 seconds
  then restart
  alert email_address@example.com only on { timeout, nonexist }
```

The syntax is fairly self-explanatory, but basically:

- The process hinges on the `apache2.pid`; be sure to change that to match the actual location of your `apache2.pid` or `httpd.pid` in your environment.
- Then has commands connected to the processes of `start` and `stop`.
- And has logic that monitors the web server on port `80` on `localhost` (`127.0.0.1`)
- And only acts of the server is unreachable for 15 seconds.
- An if it has to act, it attempts a restart.
- And then sends an alert to the specified email address on incidents of the server timing out or not existing.

#### Setting up a Monit MySQL monitoring ruleset.

Based on [the examples I linked to above](https://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/ConfigurationExamples), I would assume a config like this would work for MySQL. First, create a file like this:

```
sudo nano /etc/monit/conf.d/mysql.conf
```

And I have adapted the example so it—I would assume—behaves similarly to what I have setup for Apache:

```
check process mysqld with pidfile /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
  start program = "/usr/sbin/service mysql start"
  stop program = "/usr/sbin/service mysql stop"
  if failed host 127.0.0.1 port 3306 protocol mysql
    with timeout 15 seconds
  then restart
  alert email_address@example.com only on { timeout, nonexist }
```

Of course that should be tweaked to match your actual working environment—such as adjusting the location of the `mysqld.pid`, the email address and such—but past that it’s fairly generic in ideas/implementation.

Once that is set, restart `monit` and all should be good:

```
sudo service monit restart
```

#### Setting up a Monit MongoDB monitoring ruleset.

To create a MongoDB monitoring ruleset, create a file like this:

```
sudo nano /etc/monit/conf.d/mongod.conf
```

And here is the MongoDB monitoring rule; note this matches the active MongoDB daemon and not a PID (aka: `mongod.lock`) since it didn’t seem to work with that:

```
check process mongod matching "/usr/bin/mongod"
  start program = "/usr/sbin/service mongod start"
  stop program = "/usr/sbin/service mongod stop"
  if failed host 127.0.0.1 port 27017 protocol http
    with timeout 15 seconds
  then restart
  alert email_address@example.com only on { timeout, nonexist }
```

Of course that should be tweaked to match your actual working environment—such as adjusting the actual path of the `/usr/bin/mongod` binary, the email address and such—but past that it’s fairly generic in ideas/implementation.

Once that is set, restart `monit` and all should be good:

```
sudo service monit restart
```

#### Monitoring Monit.

You can follow the Monit log to see it in action:

```
sudo tail -f -n 200 /var/log/monit.log
```

And as a test, you can simply stop the MySQL or MongoDB server and then see what shows up in that log. If all goes well you should see the whole monitoring process and restart happen including an email being sent to the address you have set in the config.

Comment: I tested this on Ubuntu 14.04, but for me it doesn't work. After pasting in the example code that you wrote and restarted monit I tail `/var/log/monit.log`. I then manually stop mysql and mongo (`sudo service mysql stop` and `sudo service mongodb stop`). After a while I see a couple lines in the monit log about mongod: `process is not running, trying to restart, start: /usr/sbin/service, failed to start`. It notices that mongo is not running, but it doesn't seem to be able to start it again. Oh, and and about mysql I don't see anything in the logs  (waited half an hour). Any ideas?

Comment: Ah! I managed to get it to work. I changed the line with the start command to `start program = "/sbin/start mongodb"` which works for me. No idea yet why it doesn't work for mysql.

Answer (score 3):

A simple bash script (or whatever other scripting language you are familiar with) will do the job (to be run with sudo):

```
while true
do
    # Ping the MySQL server (or run a real SELECT command using mysql client)
    mysqladmin ping
    # Check the return code: should be 0 if server is alive
    if [[ $? != 0 ]]
    then
        service mysql restart
    fi
    # Wait until next check
    sleep 60
done
```

Comment: Are you sure that sudo inside an automatically-running script is such a good idea?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Indeed, it would be cleaner without sudo inside  the script. I edited.