# Why is “mysqld.pid” and “mysqld.sock” missing from my system even though the values are set in “my.cnf?”

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql

I was working on [an answer to this question](https://superuser.com/a/980559/167207)—on one of my Ubuntu 12.04.5 development servers—and realized that the MySQL install was not creating `mysqld.pid` and `mysqld.sock` files despite their paths being explicitly set in `my.cnf` like this:

```
[mysqld]
# 
# * Basic Settings
# 
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
```

Why would this happen and what can be done to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even though the locations for `mysqld.pid` and `mysqld.sock` are set in my server’s `my.cnf`, the directory doesn’t exist so those files are never created. This will fix that:

First, create the `mysqld/` directory in `/var/run/` like this:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld/
```

Then, create a `mysqld.pid` file with `touch`:

```
sudo touch /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Next, create a `mysqld.sock` file with `touch`:

```
sudo touch /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Now, change the ownership of the directory and files to `mysql:mysql` like this:

```
sudo chown mysql:mysql -R /var/run/mysqld
```

Finally, the permissions on those files should be:

```
chmod 755 /var/run/mysqld
chmod 777 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
chmod 660 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

And restart MySQL like this to get those files set and created:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

When that’s all done, MySQL will be able to to create the `mysqld.pid` and `mysqld.sock` files as expected.