# Mysql server restart failed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql

My question is exactly the same as this one here, [Why is “mysqld.pid” and “mysqld.sock” missing from my system even though the values are set in “my.cnf?”](https://superuser.com/questions/980841/why-is-mysqld-pid-and-mysqld-sock-missing-from-my-system-even-though-the-val/980842#980842?newreg=8940ca7410224b36b7a5a616d09861f9).

I followed all the steps provided in the answer, on the last step, I get an error, `Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details`.

How can I solve this?
Thanks in advance

ps: I could've asked in the comments section, but I need 50 reputation.

Comment: @slhck, `journalctl -xe` gives "No journal files were opened due to insufficient permissions." The status shows that it failed. I also ran the command `sudo find / -type s | grep mysqld.sock`, it returned "No such file or directory" for all of them. Does this mean the mysqld.sock file was not created?

Comment: To see the `journalctl` messages you need to be member of a certain user group: `sudo usermod -a -G systemd-journal $(whoami)` – otherwise you can't see the messages. Also look at errors in `/var/log` coming from Apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking the mysql error log file, there was an error `InnoDB: Error: io_setup() failed with EAGAIN after 5 attempts.`, the solution was to add `innodb_use_native_aio = 0` in /etc/mysql/my.cnf file. I then restarted the server. It's working!