# How to get Monit to re-monitor a service it has unmonitored?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, monit

While devising [an answer to this question](https://superuser.com/a/980559/167207) I ran into a snag while testing this MySQL Monit ruleset on an Ubuntu 12.04.5 setup:

```
check process mysqld with pidfile /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
  group mysql
  start program = "/etc/init.d/mysql start"
  stop program = "/etc/init.d/mysql stop"
  if failed host 127.0.0.1 port 3306
    with timeout 15 seconds
  then restart
  if 5 restarts within 5 cycles
  then timeout
  alert email_address@example.com only on { timeout, nonexist }
```

The issue is I was attempting to invoke start/stop items via `/etc/init.d/` — which is more of a CentOS/RedHat system construct — instead of using `/usr/sbin/service` which would be more appropriate for a Ubuntu/Debian system.

Okay, my bad… But the issue is you see that `if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout` part? That seems to have bit me hard. With the `/etc/init.d/mysql start` command not able to work, the system attempted 5 restarts, failed 5 times and then timed out as a result. And the timeout condition seems to result in the MySQL service ruleset being ignored my Monit.

I’ve restarted the Monit service a few times and even rejiggered the ruleset to see if it helps but none of that seems to affect anything.

What can I do to get Monit to pay attention to rulesets it has “unmonitored” due to timeout conditions being met?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After doing some digging, it turns out Monit stores system monitoring data in a “state” file. And this “state” file keeps track of what services are being monitored/unmonitored.

So while this is a bit “brute force”-ish, it definitely works. If a service becomes “unmonitored” due to something like a timeout, then just remove the Monit state file from the system like this:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/monit/state
```

And then restart Monit like this and all should be good:

```
sudo service monit restart
```

FWIW, on other systems/setups the Monit “state” file might be saved as `state` or `monit.state` or even `.monit.state` (with a dot/period `.` prepending it) in another directory. Be sure to determine exactly where that “state” file is being saved when you actually attempt to implement this fix.

Comment: On a related note, when trying to find this state file on amazon linux, I was (finally) able to find it at `/root/.monit.state`

Comment: You should be able to find the location of your `statefile` in the Monit config file (`/etc/monit/monitrc`) with e.g. `grep statefile /etc/monit/monitrc`

Answer (score 7):

Monit [includes commands](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#Arguments) to enable and disable monitoring of all or specific services.

If a service has become unmonitored you can re-enable monitoring with e.g. `monit monitor mysql` or `monit monitor all`.

Note you must have the Monit HTTP interface enabled for these commands to work.

Comment: The Monit CLI uses the HTTP interface to communicate with the Monit daemon. 

"Note that if HTTP support is disabled, the Monit CLI interface will have reduced functionality, as most CLI commands (such as "monit status") needs to communicate with the Monit background process via the HTTP interface. We strongly recommend having HTTP support enabled."  https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#MONIT-HTTPD

Now whether or not that makes sense is a question for the developers :)