# How to auto-restart linphone (graphical mode) when it closes or crashes?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, autostart

I’m using [Linphone](https://www.linphone.org) in a Raspberry Pi 3 to make a VoIP auto answer for a headset.

I’m having a problem that some times Linphone crashes.

I’d like to know how can i make it start again in graphical mode when I close it or it crashes?

In starting linphone with this code in `/home/pi/.configure/autostart/linphone.desktop`:

```
Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=linphone
Exec=/usr/bin/linphone &
```

How can I make a program OS anything that knows when Linphone closes and start it again?

Comment: I would recommend looking into using Monit to monitor whether Linphone is up or down and then act accordingly. I have very little experience with Linphone, but I [wrote up this answer on how to use Monit to restart MySQL](https://superuser.com/a/980559/167207). You would need to figure out what items on the file system (PID file) or network (port number) could be used as a clue to figure out what might have happened, but if you do then Monit can watch for that and act accordingly if the criteria is met… Or not met…

Comment: hello. it isnt working for a program that open in desktop visual mode

Comment: Well, it was an idea. While you say it launches in visual mode, the reality is something on the file system should indicate that the visual/graphical mode was initiated in some way. How to find that? I don’t know. But there has to be something there. Good luck figuring this out and hopefully someone else can post something if they have more experience with this program than me.